# How to get data from table which add row at client side?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, html-table

I have a table includes 2 columns.
And have a button "Add Row" to allow the user to add new row with 2 text boxes dynamically (by using jJvascript in order to increase the performance without post back at server).

I wish to retrieve all the values keyed by the user and save to database.

My problem is, I couldn't retrieve the table's values at server side (in .aspx.cs file) because my table is not `runat="server"`, if my table `runat="server"`, I couldn't add row at client side.

Any idea to solve this or have another alternative way to do so?

Below is my code for "Add Row":

```
function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        if (rowCount > 10) {
            alert("Only 10 rows allow");
            return false;
        }  

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.innerHTML = rowCount;

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "text";
        element1.name = "txtbox[]";
        element1.style = "width:345px;"
        cell2.appendChild(element1);

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "text";
        element2.name = "txtbox[]";
        element2.style = "width:345px;"
        cell3.appendChild(element2);
    }
```

and this is the code of the table

```
<table id="tblAddNode" width="750px" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th width="10px">No.</th>
                <th width="350px">Description</th>
                <th width="350px"> Keyword </th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td width="10px">1</td>
                <td width="350px"> <input type="text" style="width:345px;"/> </td>
                <td width="350px"> <input type="text" style="width:345px;"/> </td>
             </tr>
        </table>
```

**Edited**
Add Row Button

```
input type="button" value="Add Row" onclientclick="addRow('tblAddNode')"
```

Submit Button

```
<asp:Button ID="EnterRootNodeButton" runat="server" Text="OK" OnClick="EnterRootNode_Click"/>
```

Comment: Whatever solution you come up with using ASP.Net Forms isn't going to be pretty. You should go with an AJAX approach using a javascript Framework.

Comment: there is submit button? or you want that any click on the add button will send data to the sever?

Comment: @Dvir.. yaya there is another submit to send data to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you think you cannot manipulate the information on the client side if you mark that as runat="server", do you mean the Id is changed after that?

you can mark the id as static by adding ClientIDMode="Static" or in your javascript, instead of referring to Id, you refer to the ClientId

Also, there are multiple ways of doing that and it depends on how your solution is designed and the time you want to spend on the issue.

You can issue an ajax's call with the user input information and then post that to an API (you need to develop that). You will be save all the information added by the user.

You can also have another API to expose all the information and that enables you to reload the information (if needed in the future).

You will have better UI experience in doing this, but of course it needs more time if you are not familiar with the Ajax and webservice deign.

Comment: hi, thanks for reply.
if i put runat="server", i cant add the row by using the javascript..

Comment: I am not sure why you say that, in your button, you can have OnClick="something" or OnClientClick="something" you can have your function there

Comment: i have new added my two buttons in my question.

at aspx.cs file, at EnterRootNode_Click action there..
without the runat="server",
I tried to retrieve the number of row by using 
tblAddNode.Rows.Count,
but there is an error said that tblAddNode is not exist in the current context.

Comment: In your code behind if you need to access the tblAddNode you need to mark the table as Runat='server', or you cannot access that.you'd better stick to either full client side implementation or full server side implementation in your case. if you want to mix that, mark that as runat='server' and make the ClientIDMode='static' so that your client code doesn't break

Comment: is it putting like this?

<table id="tblAddNode" width="750px" border="1" runat="server" clientidmode="Static">

<input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('tblAddNode')"/>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38306/discussion-between-user1850936-and-stay-foolish)